# Generate random numbers distributed in 4 ranges in VBA

Tags: vba, random

I want to generate 1000 random numbers en VBA, but in frequencies as follows:

- 5% must be under 10K
- 90% must be between 10K and 50K
- 2.5% must be between 50K and 100K
- 2.5% must be over 100K

The occurrence is random and unordered.

Any suggestions about how to handle the ranges?

Thanks!

Comment: Generate 50, 900, 25, 25, numbers in the given ranges and then shuffle them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Coleman suggested the correct method including the correct shuffle algorithm. Here's the code

```
Sub GenArray()
   Dim Arr(1000) As Long  'all values
   
   For i = 1 To 50: Arr(i) = Rand(0, 10000): Next i
   For i = 51 To 950: Arr(i) = Rand(10000, 50000): Next i
   For i = 951 To 975: Arr(i) = Rand(50000, 100000): Next i
   For i = 976 To 1000: Arr(i) = Rand(100000, 200000): Next i
   
   ShuffleFY Arr
   'Shuffle Arr, 999999
End Sub

Function Rand(lv, uv)
    Rand = Int(lv + Rnd * (uv - lv))
End Function

Sub ShuffleFY(Arr() As Long)  ' Fisher–Yates shuffle
    Randomize
    For s = 1 To UBound(Arr) - 1 'start from first index
        t = Rand(s + 1, UBound(Arr))  'pick random target index
            tmp = Arr(t)    'swap indexes
            Arr(t) = Arr(s)
            Arr(s) = tmp
    Next s
End Sub

Sub Shuffle(Arr() As Long, Cnt As Long) 'Random shuffle
    Randomize
    For c = 1 To Cnt
        s = Rand(LBound(Arr), UBound(Arr)) 'pick random source index
        t = Rand(LBound(Arr), UBound(Arr)) 'pick random target index
        If (s <> t) Then
            tmp = Arr(s)     'swap indexes
            Arr(s) = Arr(t)
            Arr(t) = tmp
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice answer -- though an actual Fisher-Yates shuffle would be more efficient (albeit slightly harder to code) than `999999` pairwise swaps.